# using a global variable to store a number (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

the statement `if (xPos === xGold3 && yPos === yGold3)` , the code somehow does not recognize the values for xGold3 and yGold3 and my code does not work, but if i assign some values manually like `if (xPos === 400 && yPos === 0)` , then the code works. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>P</title>
        <style>
            div.box{ width: 600px; height: 400px; border: 5px solid black;
                margin: auto; position: relative; }

        </style>
          <button type="button" onclick="position();setGoldPos();">New Game</button>
    </head>

    <body onLoad ="getGoldPos()"  onKeyDown = "move(event)">
         <script>
             var dx = 20;
             var dy = 20;

             var xPos = 0;
             var yPos = 0;

             var xGold3 = 0;
             var yGold3 = 0;

             //generates random gold positions at the start of every game
             function getGoldPos() 
             {
                xGold3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 545) + 1);
                yGold3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 350) + 1);   
             }

             //assigns randomly generated position to image "gold3"          
             function setGoldPos()
             {
                document.getElementById("gold3").style.top= yGold3 + "px";
                document.getElementById("gold3").style.left= xGold3 + "px";
             }

             function position()
             {
                kitty = document.getElementById("sprite");
                kitty.style.left = xPos+"px";
                kitty.style.top = yPos+"px";
                if (xPos === xGold3 && yPos === yGold3)
                {
                    document.getElementById("gold3").style.top= 420 + "px";
                    document.getElementById("gold3").style.left= 0 + "px";
                }
                setTimeout("position()",10);
             }

             function move(event)
             {   
                 var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                 if ((keyPressed == "W" || keyPressed == "I" || event.keyCode == '38' ) && yPos >= 2)
                 {  
                     yPos -= dy;
                 }
                 else if ((keyPressed == "D" || keyPressed == "L" || event.keyCode == '39') && xPos <=545)
                 {  
                     xPos += dx;
                 }
                 else if ((keyPressed == "S" || keyPressed == "K" || event.keyCode == '40') && yPos <= 350)
                 {  
                     yPos += dy;
                 }
                 else if ((keyPressed == "A" || keyPressed == "J" || event.keyCode == '37') && xPos >= 3 )
                 {  
                     xPos -= dx;
                 }
              }
         </script>

         <div STYLE="text-align:center"> <h2> Use WASD or IJKL or arrow keys to move kitty </h2> </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="sprite.jpg" alt="kitty" id="sprite" width="40px" 
                            style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">

         <img id="gold3" src="gold.jpg"  style="position:absolute; 
                            left: 400; top: 100; width: 30px; height: 35px;"/>                  

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: setMonsterPos is not defined"

Comment: thanks @epascarello, that was not the issue but i removed it anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the issue. You are picking a random number and your step is by 20. So if the random number is not a factor of 20, it is impossible for them to be equal.

```
xGold3: 86  <-- actual value
xPos: 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110 <-- Possible values of X
```

With the possible values, it is not possible for `xPos` and `xGold3` to ever be equal with this specific value. When you hard coded it to a value in the if statement, `400` was a possible value for `xPos`, hence why it worked.

So either you need to position the gold on a factor of the step, or you need to be a range.

So you either need to change the random number generator to round to the nearest factor of your step OR change your if statement to see if the gold is in the range of the step. The check should be something like this: (untested)

```
if (xGold3 >= xPos && xGold3 < xPos+dx && yGold3 >= yPos && yGold3 < yPos+dy)
```

Comment: sorry if i didn't understand a part of your answer but I have set a range for generating the random number

Comment: But 0 + 20(n) can never equal 86.

Comment: @epascarello he's saying a range in the `if` check not the random number generator I think (meaning `if x > num && x < num2` )

Comment: @Chalupa I changed the explanation, hopefully that clears it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Positions will never be equal with the current code, try something like this instead to see if both x and y of the cat are within 20pxs:

```
if (Math.abs(xPos - xGold3) <= 20 && Math.abs(yPos - yGold3) <= 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I dove into it, variable type was not the issue.

This works below! Working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t7k0a395/

If you subtract the modulo of the random number to make it divisible by 20 so it will be eaqual to your step variable of 20 it works. When it gets to the gold, now the gold moves outside the box.

```
xGold3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* 545) + 1);
yGold3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* 350) + 1);
xGold3 = xGold3-(xGold3 % 20);
yGold3 = yGold3-(yGold3 % 20);
```

RGecy

REVISED: Maybe a better way would be to take the mod of xGold3 and dx and do the same for the y values. That way if you changed dx or dy, you would not need to change the mod value.

```
xGold3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* 545) + 1);
yGold3 = Math.floor((Math.random()* 350) + 1);
xGold3 = xGold3-(xGold3 % dx);
yGold3 = yGold3-(yGold3 % dy);
```

Comment: Should be the answer. Works on my end flawlessly!